# How to select and get color in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, system.drawing

As there is no integrated attribute for color in asp.net (atleast i haven't found it), i wonder, how do you guys select color?

Let's say i want to create a drawing using bitmap and i want to get background color from the user who selects it using the application.

I've done some code behind, but thing doesn't work, as i manually type in colors like #000 or #fff (using textbox)

**app.aspx**

```
<label>
<span>Background color</span>
<asp:TextBox ID="inp_bgColor" Width="125px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="error_bg" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br /><br />
```

and **app.aspx.cs**

```
Color txtClr = Color.FromName(inp_bgColor.Text);
```

I've noticed that System.Drawing.Color is type of ARGB color, so how do i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hex colors like this:

```
string hex = "#FF3FF3";
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
```

Comment: gives me and error of "an object reference is required for the non static field method or property 'TypeConverter'.ConvertFromString(string)'

Comment: running debugger, i now get desired values. Which means it probably works. So codebehind is "done".

Comment: what about frontend, how do i let user choose color from like a colorpicker or sth, so that he doesn't need to write in hex values?

Answer (score 1):

The Color.FromName method gets colors from the KnownColor enumeration (see [know color table](http://www.flounder.com/csharp_color_table.htm)
Try using the Color.FromARGB method see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx)
For simple user color picking you can use the color dialog like this:

```
// Show the color dialog.
ColorDialog colorDialog1=new ColorDialog();
DialogResult result = colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
// See if user pressed ok.
Color selectedColor;
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    selectedColor = colorDialog1.Color;
}
```

Comment: running debugger, i now get desired values. Which means it probably works. So codebehind is "done". what about frontend, how do i let user choose color from like a colorpicker or sth, so that he doesn't need to write in hex values?

Comment: thanks buddy, but already got it working with abdul's post. hope this helps any other tho :) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can get color using `.Attributes.CssStyle["color"]`, but your element must have css style property like color set.

```
 inp_bgColor.Attributes.CssStyle["color"]
```

And  you can use this way to convert

```
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
```